# Is it possible to move the search index location in SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint Foundation 2013, is it possible to change the search index location in PowerShell? I can't seem to clone the current topology getting the error "Access to this functionality requires a SharePoint Server Client Access License."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the needed PowerShell commands are only available in the "bigger" versions of SharePoint 2013. 
The only option I found for changing the location of the index is to reinstall the server and to choose the right path in the "Data location"-tab at the beginning of the setup.